# CircleCI manually approved Deployment with Rollback

Tags: circleci-2.0

The new CircleCI 2.0 configuration allows to have a step of type `approve` which waits for user input. Is there some way to not just deploy code using manual stop, but also have a rollback to a previous version based on user input?

Comment: Like git revert?

Comment: The scenario I was thinking is deployment of the previous build artifact back. It seems there is only a deployment of current artifact, no way to specify which.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, no.

The best ways to rollback would be to use `git revert`, which then adds the rollback to history (which is a good thing), and then push that like any other commit. The other would be to use the git hash of the commit you'd like to rollback to and build it with the CircleCI API.

Right now, you could also attempt to rebuild and older build via the UI but this isn't suggest for deploys & Workflows. Too many variables for safe, reproducible deploys.

- Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: The problem with this is that you need to rebuild containers.  Rolling back to a previous container, without rebuilding it, reduces the risk of introducing new bugs.  New container means new test cycle, which means delaying a potentially critical rollback.